# How to uncomment code block in emacs python-mode?

Tags: emacs, python-mode

I just started using python-mode in emacs and I noticed that while the major mode has an option for commenting out a region (`(py-comment-region)` which is bound  `(C-c #)`)there is no option to uncomment the code block which is already commented. I checked all the active keybinds in python-mode and could not find any relevant key. Am I missing something?

I did think of a couple of work arounds like using `(delete-rectangular)` (bound to `C-x r d`) to delete the comments.
Another method would be to bind the `(comment-or-uncomment-region)` to some key and start using that.

But is there any option provided in python-mode itself by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using `comment-dwim` which is really smart and can be used for both commenting and un-commenting active regions. It works for the python mode as well.

You can find more information in [emacs comment commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Comment-Commands.html).

Answer (score 17):

Not sure about your setup but I use `M-;` and it works for me.

Answer (score 11):

> ## How to uncomment code block in emacs python-mode?

Select code, e.g. with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd> to mark and cursor over desired code.

Then, meta-semicolon: <kbd>Meta</kbd>-<kbd>;</kbd>

That's <kbd>escape</kbd> then <kbd>;</kbd>s or hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>;</kbd>

The same method will also comment code.

Answer (score 2):

Most comment region functions will uncomment a region with `C-u comment-region-function`

Comment: When I use `C-u`, emacs instantly changes the text selection to the beginning of the file to the first letter of my last selection.